Moving objects around the image
I have a problem with my Android app that I can't solve in any way. I used the AR Tracked Image Manager and my own code to display different objects in different photos. My question is as follows. Is it possible to somehow implement the movement of objects in the image?
I tried to do it myself by grabbing the object with my finger, but as soon as I release it, the object returns to the center of the image
Screen 1
Screen 2
The code that allows you to display multiple objects
public class MultipleImagesTrackingManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ARTrackedImageManager trackedImageManager;
    public GameObject[] objectsToSpawn;

    private Dictionary<string, GameObject> trackedObjects = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();

    void Start()
    {
        // Подписываемся на события обнаружения и потери изображений
        trackedImageManager.trackedImagesChanged += OnTrackedImagesChanged;
    }

    void OnTrackedImagesChanged(ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        foreach (var trackedImage in eventArgs.added)
        {
            // Создаем новый объект на основе изображения, если он еще не существует
            if (!trackedObjects.ContainsKey(trackedImage.referenceImage.name))
            {
                GameObject objectToSpawn = GetObjectToSpawn(trackedImage.referenceImage.name);
                if (objectToSpawn != null)
                {
                    GameObject spawnedObject = Instantiate(objectToSpawn, trackedImage.transform.position, trackedImage.transform.rotation);
                    trackedObjects.Add(trackedImage.referenceImage.name, spawnedObject);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var trackedImage in eventArgs.updated)
        {
            // Обновляем положение и поворот объекта, связанного с изображением
            if (trackedObjects.ContainsKey(trackedImage.referenceImage.name))
            {
                trackedObjects[trackedImage.referenceImage.name].transform.position = trackedImage.transform.position;
                trackedObjects[trackedImage.referenceImage.name].transform.rotation = trackedImage.transform.rotation;
            }
        }

        foreach (var trackedImage in eventArgs.removed)
        {
            // Удаляем объект, связанный с удаленным изображением
            if (trackedObjects.ContainsKey(trackedImage.referenceImage.name))
            {
                Destroy(trackedObjects[trackedImage.referenceImage.name]);
                trackedObjects.Remove(trackedImage.referenceImage.name);
            }
        }
    }

    GameObject GetObjectToSpawn(string imageName)
    {
        // Находим соответствующий объект для конкретного изображения
        foreach (var obj in objectsToSpawn)
        {
            if (obj.name == imageName)
            {
                return obj;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

